# How can I replace ordered list number with an icon on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, list

I have a simple ordered list:

```
<ol>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ol>
```

I'm using jQuery to make a sortable list where you can drag and drop to reorder items in the list.  But I'd also like users to be able to delete list items by clicking an "x" icon where the ordered list number typically is on hover.  The right side is already used by a "move" icon (three horizontal lines).

If I were hovering over list item 2, I would expect to see:

```
1. one
X  two     =
3. three
```

I need the 2 replaced with an `X` and it to be clickable.

(Note: the `=` above is meant to symbolize the move hover icon, typically three horizontal lines.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you won't be able to change an ordered list into an unordered list (to just swap out the number into an X on the fly like that).

Instead have an unordered list with the Numbers being laid out in span tags that we can swap out for the X (image / whatever you want). This way it's easy to bind the delete event onto that as well!

**css**  ul li { list-style-type: none; }

```
<ul>
    <li><span>1.</span> one</li>
    <li><span>2.</span> two</li>
    <li><span>3.</span> three</li>
</ul>
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8JAka/2/)

```
$('ul li').each(function () { 
    var this$ = $(this),
        _old = $(this).find('span').text();

    this$.on({
        mouseover: function () {
            this$.find('span').text('X');
        }, 
        mouseout: function () {
            this$.find('span').text(_old);
        }
    });

    this$.find('span').on('click', function () {
         if ( $(this).text() === 'X') {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?')) {
                $(this).closest('li').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
​
```

Comment: this would also mean you would have to update the numbers in the script when you change the order. You could just lay a delete icon on top of the number in an ordered list... Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zz5RJ/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are three good ways to use an image as a list bullet:

1. Use `list-style-image` to replace the bullet on `:hover`.  The weakness of this approach is that the image cannot really be positioned and your constrained by the image's size.

   http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/tCTwJ/

   ```
   li:hover {
       list-style-image: url(x.png);
   }
   ```
2. Use `list-style-type: none` to hide the bullet and use a `:before` pseudo-element to place an image.  This won't work on IE7.

   http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/LVsYW/

   ```
   li {
       position: relative;
   }

   li:hover {
       list-style-type: none;
   }

   li:hover:before {
       content: '';
       width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       margin-top: -25px;
       left: -55px;
       background-image: url(x.png);
   }
   ```
3. Similar to 2, you could carefully adjust the margin and padding of your element and place a non-repeating background image in it.  This is probably the most reliable approach but it boxes you in to a very specific set of styles.

   http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/LXe4C/

   ```
   li:hover {
       list-style-type: none;
       background-image: url(x.png);
       background-position: 0 50%;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       margin-left: -55px;
       padding-left: 55px;
   }​
   ```

Comment: For me option 2 is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You could put your icon in a span and position it absolutely. Then just show it on hover of the LI.

http://jsfiddle.net/S3Ph8/1/

Comment: this is the same solution i was working on, with the actual delete working though: http://jsfiddle.net/Zz5RJ/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new css class for deleting an item

```
li.remove
{
 background-image: url(remove.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0 50%;
 padding: 3px 0 3px 20px;
 margin: .4em 0;
}
```

Then create a hover event handler to add that class to the highlighted li

```
$('ul li').on('hover', function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('remove');
}).on('click', function(){
   alert($(this).text());    
//take some action
})
```

This is to give you a rough idea, you need to tweak it to your requirement, plus of course have an actual gif